# Uploading file using local upload?

Tags: testrigor

I'm testing a site that only allows uploading thru a native dialog box. Anyway to make this work?

[image: 1]

Automating file upload using native dialog box thru testrigor

Answer (score 0):

You could try to upload the file into test data then use:

**enter stored value "fileName" into "Upload data from file"**

This will work in the case **"Upload data from file"** is a file input element, i.e.: *input type="file" ...*

Alternatively you can use your own URL. If you choose to upload from your own URL, the link should be downloable.